# Object destruction and null links

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destroy

I am very confused. I have always assumed that as long as there is at least one link to an object in C#, the object will keep existing, and the only way to destroy the object completely is to eliminate all the links (by setting them to `null` or something else), and wait for GC to destroy it.

But experiments with Unity3D now led me to think that this belief is inaccurate, as demonstrated by the code:

```
GameObject objA = new GameObject();
Debug.Log("Is null: " + (objA == null));
GameObject.DestroyImmediate(objA);
Debug.Log("Now is null: " + (objA == null));
```

And the output is two mesasges:

```
Is null: False
Now is null: True
```

So, by merely calling some magical method `DestroyImmediate` I can get rid of my object, and more, the link `objA` is automatically reset to `null`! How in the world can this be? Can you imagine what is inside of `DestroyImmediate`? Can this be done in normal C# at all, or is this some dirty trick of Mono and/or Unity3D?

*UPDATE*: as was pointed out to me, the experiment doesn't actually prove that the object is destroyed. But that is not my main concern. My main concern is that the link somehow got nullified.

Comment: Perhaps the `GameObject` class overloaded the equals operator?  Maybe `object.ReferenceEquals` will give the appropriate result?

Comment: @TrevorElliott Nice idea! But I've checked, `GameObject` doesn't overload `ReferenceEquals`. Its only ancestor, called `UnityEngine.Object`, doesn't overload `ReferenceEquals` either. It does overload `Equals`, but I doubt that it is relevant.

Comment: Maybe there's some crazy reflection mechanism that, given a reference to an object, can somehow access ALL the other references to this object?

Comment: Reference for [`DestroyImmediate` method](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Object.DestroyImmediate.html).

Comment: Why would it need to override ReferenceEquals?  ReferenceEquals is not overridable, it's a static method.  You just said it overloads Equals.  Have you tried debugging and seeing what the debugger says the variable is assigned?  And you can try calling a method on the object such as `objA.ToString()` as a test.  If it were really null you'd get a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: @Jeppe I've seen the reference, it still doesn't explain how this is done. Besides, who knows, given the overall style of that reference, "destroyed" there can very well mean just "removed from the scene".

Comment: @Trevor, OK, you are right, it is not really `null`. Looks like it's the object somehow marked as invalid. objA.ToString() produces string "null", not an exception. Now I'm quite new to c#, but docs left me under impression that when == is evaluated, the overridden operator == is called, and not the Equals(). Was I wrong?

Comment: @Trevor OK, I got it. I just didn't see the `static operator == ()` in the assembly browser because I wasn't looking in the right place. It is there, mistery solved.

Answer (score 2):

You can use reflector to see inside the .NET assemblies: http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/reflector/ and check their code.

Comment: If you pass an object to a method and that method sets the object to `null` it won't affect the reference variable outside the method (unless you use the `ref` keyword).

Comment: @TrevorElliott You're right, I'll remove that part of my answer.

Comment: It's a good answer, I would have used ILSpy on it if I had Unity framework downloaded.

Comment: OK, thanks, I'll look into it. Will take some time though, this tool is new to me.

Answer (score 1):

OK, thanks to Trevor the truth emerged quickly.

`objA` doesn't actually get assigned `null`. Instead, the object itself changes, and the overloaded == operator begins to return `true` when compared to `null`.